# Mouse cursor didn't work remote connection program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, remote-access, remote-desktop

https://github.com/KaramanisWeb/RemoteDesktopOverNetwork

I downloaded this project and run it, every thing was ok just mouse curser didn't work.

this is a remote connection project with C# and I need mouse get work.

this project with this problem (mouse its not controllable) looks like screen sharing .

but I need to control the mouse from remote .

additionally, I checked mouse control check box at server side but mouse didn't control at client side.

[image: Picture]

Some similar code to mouse:

```
Bitmap NewIM = ScreenCapture.CaptureSelectedScreen(desktopSelected, cbMouse.Checked);
byte[] newIMdata = NewIM.ToByteArray(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking

Comment: @uwe-keim hello , could you please test this source project ?

Comment: For this, you ought to submit an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/KaramanisWeb/RemoteDesktopOverNetwork/issues).

Comment: @kyle-wang dear kyle-wang , the project owner didn't get online until now . I need to solve this problem as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I need this project and the mouse cursor didn't work